ng2-smart-table does not support angular 17.3.8 version?
I am upgrading angular cli version from 11 to version 17.x.x when I tried upgrading packages ng2-smart-table and tslint-language-service packages doesn't support angular version 17.It's stating to downgrade the peer dependencies.

This library has not been updated in years. It is expected that with without any updates, the library may stop working with new Angular versions. The owner of the library stated that it's is in low maintenance. There seems to be a guy who forked the library. The fork has recent commits and seems to support Angular 17. You can try using the forked version of the library instead.
Regarding tslint-language-service, this has been deprecated for a long time. You can migrate to Angular ESLint with the help of their migration guide.

Upgrading 6 major versions can bring a lot of compatibility issues, espescially since ng2-smart-table and tslint-language-service have not been updated in years.
You can check their respective github repositories and issues for alternatives/forks of these projects.
For ng2-smart-table you could look into other table libraries like ag-grid, ngx-datatable, or angular-material-table, which are all well maintained and updated.
For tslint-language-service: Since TSLint has been deprecated in favor of ESLint, it's a good time to switch to ESLint. You can use the typescript-eslint package for linting TypeScript code in Angular projects.
